# Conflito entre 2 scripts

Tags: javascript, ajax

Quando coloco o segundo script o primeiro desaparece é das primeiras vezes a usar ajax.

**Chamo os scripts assim:**

```html
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="script.js">
</script>


<div id="relogio"></div>





<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="proparagem.js">
</script>

<div id="proparagem"></div>

</div>
```

**O script.js:**

```
  var req;

function loadXMLDoc(url)
{
    req = null;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.onreadystatechange = processReqChange;
        req.open("GET", url, true);
        req.send(null);

    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        try {
req = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.4.0");
} catch(e) {
try {
req = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.3.0");
} catch(e) {
try {
req = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
} catch(e) {
try {
req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); 
} catch(e) {
req = false;
}
}
}
}
        if (req) {
            req.onreadystatechange = processReqChange;
            req.open("GET", url, true);
            req.send();
        }
    }
}

function processReqChange()
{

    if (req.readyState == 4) {

        if (req.status == 200) {

            document.getElementById('relogio').innerHTML = req.responseText;
        } else {

        }
    }
}

function buscarTempo()
{
    loadXMLDoc("relogio.php");
}


setInterval("buscarTempo()", 1000);
```

**O proparagem.js**

```
var req1;

function loadXMLDoc(url2)
{
    req1 = null;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        req1 = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req1.onreadystatechange = processReq1Change;
        req1.open("GET", url2, true);
        req1.send(null);

    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        try {
req1 = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.4.0"); 
} catch(e) {
try {
req1 = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.3.0"); 
} catch(e) {
try {
req1 = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); 
} catch(e) {
try {
req1 = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); 
} catch(e) {
req1 = false;
}


}
}
}
        if (req1) {
            req1.onreadystatechange = processReq1Change;
            req1.open("GET", url2, true);
            req1.send();
        }
    }
}

function processReq1Change()
{

    if (req1.readyState == 4) {

        if (req1.status == 200) {

            document.getElementById('proparagem').innerHTML = req1.responseText;
        } else {

        }
    }
}

function buscarTempo()
{
    loadXMLDoc("compararhorarios.php");
}


setInterval("buscarTempo()",  30000);
```

Eles são iguais so mudei o Req para Req1 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tiago, o que está acontecendo é: as suas função `loadXMLDoc` e `buscarTempo` estão no escopo global e com o mesmo nome nos dois arquivos. Assim quando o segundo script é carregado, ele simplesmente sobrescreve a função que estava no seu primeiro script.

Tente modificar o nome das suas funções.

Comment: Foi exactamente isso obrigado